# Add Function to Prototype of Number

Tags: javascript, node.js

Note I am aware that this is a bad practice. I am just trying to learn how JS works.

I added a function under `Number.prototype`:

```
Number.prototype.times = function(f){
  for(let i=0; i<Math.floor(this); i++){
    f(i);
  }
}
```

and try to invoke it by:

```
3.times( ()=>console.log("Hello") )                 //ERROR AS EXPECTED SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Number(3).times( ()=>console.log("Hello") )         //WORKING. WHY?
new Number(3).times( ()=>console.log("Hello") )     //WORKING AS EXPECTED
```

As far as I know, `Number()` just returns a primitive number type, and should not work in this case and should error like the first case. Why does it work?

```
typeof(3)            //number
typeof(Number(3))    //number
typeof(new Number(3))//object
```

I am using node-v.9.2

Comment: Just like other Number methods (.toString, .toFixed, .toPrecision, toExponential etc) you have to either use `3..times` when dealing with an integer, or `(3).times` or `var x = 3; x.times` etc - as far as why things work when you don't expect them to ... learn about javascript coercion

Comment: can u answer this also please https://stackoverflow.com/q/72508069/18428274

Answer (score 11):

It thinks the `.` is a decimal point.

`(3).times( ... )` should work.

```js
Number.prototype.times = function(f){
  for(let i=0; i<Math.floor(this); i++){
    f(i);
  }
};

(3).times(console.log);
```

Comment: Isn't 3 just a primitive number? Does it get box-ed into object? Also would this be considered a bug?

Comment: @texasbruce All JS datatypes will get boxed if you try to access their properties.

Comment: I mean why is it necessary to add parenthesis or extra dot? Is it designed to behave like this, or a parser bug?

Comment: `(3).times ((i)=>console.log(i));
   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'times' of undefined` But `3..times` works.

Comment: I think you made a mistake because `(3).times` *does* work. Check out the example I've added to my answer.

Comment: @user3297291 You are right. It works, when I put a semicolon after the curly brace. If it is missing, it complains. I am confused why because a new line is supposed to break the previous statement

Comment: Because the new line starts with a `(`, you'll need a semicolon after your function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide parenthesis because your number literal is formally unfinished when you type `3.`, parser reads it as the start of a decimal point number, that's why it throws `Syntax Error: invalid token`.

Thus you need to formally terminate your decimal point notation to indicate to parser that it can start wrapping the value into a corresponding type object representation, for example by adding another `.` like `3..times` since skipping decimal part after dot is permitted by parser.

When you do `Number(3).times(...)`, Number function usually does conversion to type Number, but this time it just returns the number as is and thus since the returned value is fully formed and parse ready that's why you can continue with aforementioned boxing logic without any errors.

Hope this clarifies a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Second is a global function that converts the argument to a Number. Number(3) works like putting 3 in parentheses.